# Starting WiFi at specified time

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. I wanted to make an app that can switch WiFi on or off at time specified by the user. I am unaware what concepts to use. Can anyone help me out how to start and proceed on?

Following code starts WiFi as soon as I press the button. Can anyone please help me out?

MainActivity.java:-

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button wifiButton, dataButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wifiButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wifiEnableButton);
    dataButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dataEnableButton);

    wifiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WifiTimeActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

WifiTimeActivity.java:-

```
public class WifiTimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TimePicker timePickerForWifi;
private Button wifiSetTimeButton;
public static int buttonPressed = 0;
public static long milliseconds;
public static int firstRun = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi_time);

    timePickerForWifi = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePickerForWifi);
    wifiSetTimeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wifiTimeSetButton);

    wifiSetTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonPressed = 1;
            milliseconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(timePickerForWifi.getCurrentHour()) +
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(timePickerForWifi.getCurrentMinute()));
            startService(new Intent(WifiTimeActivity.this, WifiService.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Timer Set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

WifiService.java:-

```
public class WifiService extends Service {
private AlarmManager alarmManager;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

public WifiService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    String WIFI_ACTION = WifiReceiver.WIFI_START;
    Intent intent = new Intent(WIFI_ACTION);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (WifiTimeActivity.buttonPressed == 1) {
        int alarmType = AlarmManager.RTC;
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(alarmType, WifiTimeActivity.milliseconds, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                alarmIntent);
    }
    else {
        alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            if (wifiManager != null) {
                if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                    if (wifiManager.getWifiState() != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING) {
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
}
```

WifiReceiver:-

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String WIFI_START = "com.sohamchari.mytasker.WIFI_START";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, WifiService.class);
    context.startService(startIntent);
}
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This is an “I want a pony” question and it’s too broad to give a specific technical answer, making it off-topic here on Stack Overflow. You’ll need to attempt to solve this problem and show your code so we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level as well as to demonstrate your commitment to solving this problem.

Comment: Please add more details to your question, things tried/ failed

Comment: Should i proceed on with services?. I had tried Broadcast receiver but do not know whether it will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could learn [Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) class which is used to trigger an operation outside the lifetime of your application.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see that.